# On the argument structure of 'bet'

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees, theta-role

I have some problems with defining the argument structure of *bet* in the following pair of sentences:

a) John bet £300 on Manchester United.

b) John bet Bill £300 that Manchester United would win the match.

Problems I have:

i) Is the argument structure of a) <SUBJ, OBJ, OBL**θ**>?

ii) In the argument structure of b) <SUBJ, Bill, OBJ, *that*-clause>, I'm not sure whether *Bill* is an indirect object, or an oblique theta role? As for the *that*-clause, is it also an object, or a complement?

iii) Could someone please tell me how to draw a tree for the argument structure of a transitive verb/(what seems like in the case of b)a tri-transitive verb?

Any help will be immensely appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: *bet* is tritransitive, but its arguments can be elided. All objects are complements; "object" is just what we call a nominal complement rather than a prepositional or clausal complement. I don't personally think that the label "indirect object" is helpful so I can't answer that (I don't think we ever used the label in my 4 year linguistics degree.) As for drawing trees, it depends on exactly which linguistic framework you're using, there are many valid ways to illustrate a sentence!

Comment: Like _vote_ and _promise_, bet_ has a very peculiar subcategorization. One of the arguments may be a monetary consideration, for instance, though that can be supplied separately, especially if it's a barter bet, like eating one's hat. Any human NP occurring immediately after _bet_ will be considered to be the other partner (with the subject) of the ensuing bet. Also, it's performative -- issuing a bet with "I bet" and receiving addressee's acceptance means that one may now speak of the bet as a binding obligation on both parties.